# I want to identify the Array with a String which I got from a View before with Segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im a absolute beginner and my English isn't well .
I would like to create a program for a person who wants to learn German.
He can pick up a topic from a picker view and then display the translation in a table view with audio and a picture.
My problem right now is that I can send the topic(SegueStatus1) from the Picker view to my table view( which contains all the arrays), but I can not identify the array with the variable that I had before. I have now manually selected the Array(Aile).

**The TABLEVIEW**

```
    import UIKit
```

// Two Arrays which can be chosen

```
     var Aile = ["Anne","Baba","Dede"]
     var ABC = ["A","B","C"]
     var myIndex = 0
class TableEins: UITableViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {super.viewDidLoad()}
```

//Two Strings from View before

```
    var SegueStatus1: String?
    var SegueStatus2: String?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {return Aile.count}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Aile[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
              myIndex = indexPath.row
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "AuswendigLernenSegue2", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**I am thankful for every help**

**EDIT :**

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

    if (segue.identifier == "AuswendigLernenSegue")
    {   
        let Status1: TableEins = segue.destination as! TableEins
        Status1.SegueStatus1 = KonuT.text
    }
```

I have a pickerView and a tableView both are working.
In the next step I want the pickerView and the tableView being connected.
The variable that determines which array I want to display is SeagueStatus1.
I want to use a solution that gets my variable right where the name of the array is needed.

Comment: New developers don't understand the importance of clean coding. Which is a shame because it helps us understand code especially if there is a language barrier. I suggest you clean your code up a bit to help others understand it better.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. But maybe all you really need to do is store the index path as a class variable in the `didSelectRowAt` method so you can reference it again in the `prepareForSegue` method so you know what `Aile` to pass.

Comment: I am very sorry for my unclean coding and my indistinctness. I copy a lot in the forums and adapt them only to my variables. I will try to comment more. I've been programming for 1 week and trying to get smart on forums without really knowing if it's going to do it right.

Comment: Yah I figured that was the case. Did my comment help at all?. If you're still confused, I can try to write an example. I personally don't use storyboards (which means I never use segues) so I'd have to look at some references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
class TableEins: UITableViewController {
    // Avoid using magic strings.
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let segueIdentifier = "AuswendigLernenSegue2"

    // Always use lowercases for your variable and make them `let` unless you're going to manipulate them later. This tells everyone it's set only once and never modified.
    // Also avoid global variables, I nested these inside the TableEins.
    // Use snake case (ex: someVariable) for all variables.  This lets someone identify the variable easily from classes and makes your code less confusing.
    let aile = ["Anne","Baba","Dede"]
    let abc = ["A","B","C"]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return aile.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = aile[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // This will always perform this segue no matter what cell you click on.
        // If you want to perform this segue on only some of the cells, you need to check the index paths
        performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: indexPath)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        // Guard is a great way to prevent from having too many nested if statetments and knowing your method execution stops here.
        guard segue.identifier == segueIdentifier else { return }

        // Get the index path from the sender
        guard let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }

        // Get your data using the index path and pass it to your view controller we are navigating to
        // You were loading the TableEins as the destination view controller. Thats this class. You may have made a mistake here.
    }
}
```